Log didin't write into filename that specified in log4j2-spring.xml file
Spring boot version 3.3.3, in my linux system I will have two tomcat instance under /opt, one is called /opt/tomcat (which is the dev environment, specified in conf/catalina.properties with spring.profiles.active=dev), another folder called /opt/tomcat_qa, also specified the profile to qa.
I want to use the SLF4j with log4j2, therefore in my pom.xml it will looks like this:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.3</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
        <artifactId>yyy</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <name>OAuth2Server</name>
        <description>OAuth2Server</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>21</java.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
                <version>9.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
                <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
                <artifactId>spotbugs-annotations</artifactId>
                <version>4.8.4</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- comman lang -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                <version>3.15.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- 实现对 Actuator 的自动化配置 -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <!-- SLF4J API -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.16</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Log4j2 Core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.24.0</version> <!-- 使用适合你的项目的版本 -->
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Log4j2 API -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.24.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Log4j to SLF4J Bridge -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-slf4j2-impl</artifactId>
                <version>2.24.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>
            <finalName>EppAuthServer</finalName>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>4.0.0.4121</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>
                                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                                <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
                            </exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jasypt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.5</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>maven_central</id>
                <name>Maven Central</name>
                <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    
    
    </project>

Also I create the log4j2-spring.xml file which will looks like this:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    
    <!--TRACE < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL < OFF-->
    <Configuration status="OFF" monitorInterval="30">
    
        <!-- 定义一些变量值，可供下面配置使用，例如日志存储目录等 -->
        <Properties>
            <Property name="APP_NAME">AuthServer</Property>
            <Property name="LOG_HOME">${spring:logging.base}/logs</Property>
            <Property name="SPLIT_SIZE">20 MB</Property>
        </Properties>
        <!-- appenders that kind of the stuff.... -->
        <Appenders>
            <!-- 以 年-月 创建文件夹，每天滚动一次，每个文件最大20M，最多保存50个文件-->
            <RollingRandomAccessFile name="InfoLog" fileName="${LOG_HOME}/${APP_NAME}-info.log"
                                 filePattern="${LOG_HOME}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/${APP_NAME}-info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.zip"
                                 immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <!-- rest of the stuff -->
            </RollingRandomAccessFile>
            <RollingFile name="ErrorLog" fileName="${LOG_HOME}/${APP_NAME}-error.log"
                     filePattern="${LOG_HOME}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/${APP_NAME}-error-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-%i.log"
                     immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <!-- rest of the stuff -->
            </RollingFile>
        </Appenders>    
    </Configuration>

and in my application.yaml file I set it up like following:
    # other config
    logging:
      base: /opt/tomcat #(for the QA will be /opt/tomcat_qa)
      config: classpath:log4j2-spring.xml

My QA was fine, all the INFO or higher will write to AuthServer-info.log and ERROR log will write to AuthServer-Error.log, also with the catalina.out.
But for my dev, no matter how I change the config, AuthServer-info.log and AuthServer-error.log are not updated, and all the log was write to catalina.out.
Is it somewhere I need to modify on my dev tomcat instances?
EDIT: one more thing I can think about is it because RollingRandomAccessFile and RollingFile? (Just test.. error log works as expected but my info log still in catalina.out...
Also I hard code in log4j2-spring.xml file for the property         <Property name="LOG_HOME">/opt/tomcat/logs</Property>, for the INFO it still write it to catalina.out ... and my info log was not updated ...And I cannot reproduce in my computer too, only when I deploy the thing to dev server.. is it because someone else change the dev searver?

Your Spring Boot Application is a WAR file, deployed to Tomcat Server for execution?

@life888888 yes

(1) You mentioned that you have settings: spring.profiles.active=dev , spring.profiles.active=qa. (2) Where does your application.yaml and log4j2-spring.xml correspond to spring.profiles.active=dev or spring.profiles.active=qa

@life888888 in the application.yml file I set it up spring:config:activate:on-profile: dev and spring:config:activate:on-profile: qa  (seperate by ---) and log4j2-spring.xmlis in src/main/resources on my source code

(1) I cannot reproduce your error. In my environment, QA can output and execute normally. (2) Only my settings are partially different. I use application.properties and application-dev. properties , application-qa.properties (3) My application-qa.properties content: logging.base=/home/demo/apache-tomcat-10.1.28_qa and new line,
logging.config=classpath:log4j2-spring.xml (4) My tomcat is downloaded and decompressed by itself, not through apt install or yum install

Your configuration file does not have a Loggers element, which specifies which logger is connected to which appender.
